# Trouble using toggleClass on a specific element in the 'success:' part of an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been stuck on this for over a week.  I have googled, read two books, read many many stack exchange threads, visited W3 schools, watched youtube videos...  It is a simple problem...it is probably right in front of my face.  I just can't figure it out.

I'm using jQuery for an ajax call in WordPress to add/remove one post object to another post object.  Basically a bookmark.  I have figured out all of it...the php, the javascript, and everything works except for one final superficial item:

I just want to toggle the add/remove link in the 'success:' part of the ajax call.  My issue is that when I click the add/remove button...the link/text toggles...but it toggles for every link on the page.  I have tried every combination of parent(), find(), sibling(), etc...and it continues to target all of the elements of that class.  I can't seem to use 'this' because I'm not in an event anymore...I'm in the 'success:' function.

I'll try to explain with some code:

The links are dynamically generated (PHP):

```
<div class='fly_box_controls'>
     <a href='' class='add_fly' onclick=\"ftFlyBox($flyID, $flyBoxID, 'addFly', 'ftFlyBox'); return false\">Add</a>
     <a href='' class='remove_fly hidden'  onclick=\"ftFlyBox($flyID, $flyBoxID, 'removeFly', 'ftFlyBox'); return false\";>Remove</a>
</div>
```

This is the function that is called when the add/remove link is clicked:

```
function ftFlyBox(flyID, flyBoxID, doAction, action) {
   
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
       
        url: ftflyBoxUrl.ajaxurl,
        data: {flyID: flyID, flyBoxID: flyBoxID, doAction: doAction, action: action},
        
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('.add_fly').toggleClass('hidden');
            jQuery('.remove_fly').toggleClass('hidden');


        }
    });

}
```

When the add/remove link is clicked...it actually toggles properly in the browser...it's just toggling all of the other add/remove links as well.  Selecting with 'this' doesn't seem to work because I'm not in the click event anymore.  I have tried using going up a parent and then find() or next() or sibling()...to no avail.

Please help :)

Comment: Hi, can you show full jquery code  as well as html ?

Comment: I added the full jQuery above.  The html is really messy and convoluted (Elementor...) what I showed above is for simplicities sake...if you need more let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `this` as well inside your function where `this` refer to current `a` tag which is clicked then using this get closest div from `a` tag and use `.find()` to hide/show .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function ftFlyBox(flyID, flyBoxID, doAction, action, el) {
  var elements = $(el).closest(".fly_box_controls") //get closest div
  /*jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ftflyBoxUrl.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      flyID: flyID,
      flyBoxID: flyBoxID,
      doAction: doAction,
      action: action
    },
    success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);*/
  //toggleclass
  elements.find(".add_fly ,.remove_fly").toggleClass('hidden');
  /*}
  });*/
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1
<div class='fly_box_controls'>
  <!--pass `this` as well-->
  <a href='' class='add_fly' onclick="ftFlyBox(1, 1, 'addFly', 'ftFlyBox',this);return false">Add</a>
  <a href='' class='remove_fly hidden' onclick="ftFlyBox(1, 1, 'removeFly', 'ftFlyBox',this);return false;">Remove</a>
</div>
2
<div class='fly_box_controls'>
  <!--pass `this` as well-->
  <a href='' class='add_fly' onclick="ftFlyBox(2, 2, 'addFly', 'ftFlyBox',this);return false">Add</a>
  <a href='' class='remove_fly hidden' onclick="ftFlyBox(2,2, 'removeFly', 'ftFlyBox',this);return false" ;>Remove</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much.  I had no idea you could pass 'this' like that.  Thanks again.